# React-Native Promise

Tags: android, promise, react-native

I have a method in android native something like below :

```
    @ReactMethod
    public void showReject(String message, int duration, Promise promise) {
        Toast.makeText(
                reactContext, message, duration
        ).show();
        promise.reject("Success Reject", "sjdnsj");

    }
```

I am calling this method from react-native like :

```
import ToastExample from './src/view/ToastModule'


  _Decrement = async () => {

     await ToastExample.showReject('Example', ToastExample.long)
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((data) => console.log(data.toString()));


  }
```

**Questions :**

**1.** Even if i don't pass any value to promise from react-native still i get the callback from it. When above method was called i got the result in catch. How react-native promise work can anyone can explain me ?  How `promise` is initialized in native and invoked its method ?

**2.** Can i pass promise as parameter and invoke its method ?

Anybody can help in it.

Comment: Hi..while we encourage you to involve in the community, please don’t thank in the question. It eventually degrades the quality of the site. See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 0):

You do no resolve the promise in your native code (use promise.resolve() and not reject).
Promise.reject goes to catch block while resolve goes to the then block.

You are using both `await` and `then`. Try using one of them, you can write the function as `async` like so

```
async function decrement() {
  try {
    const resovled = await ToastExample.showReject('Example', ToastExample.long);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

or using then syntax

```
function decrement() {
  ToastExample.showReject('Example', ToastExample.long)
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error);
}
```